# summary statistics of groups at different scales/units

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, ranking, types-of-averages

I have these made up observations:

```
dat <- tribble(
    ~group, ~achieved, ~aim,
    "a", 10, 9.6,
    "a", 11, 10,
    "a", 10, 8.2,
    "b", 110, 93.5,
    "b", 130, 100.1234,
    "b", 70, 84.34
    )
```

[image]

There are 2 groups (there many more groups in the the actual data). The column achieved is a measurement of what was achieved at a point in time and the column aim is what was the aim at this time. If achieved is greater than aim, that's better. As you can see the groups have different scales (and possibly units in the actual data). Can one somehow summarise the average performance (residuals) per group to have a scale independent measure of performance per group?

I tried z scoring each column as follows but maybe I should just calculate the median/mean percentage difference?

```
dat$z_scored_achieved <- ave(dat$achieved, dat$group, FUN=scale)
dat$z_scored_aim <- ave(dat$aim, dat$group, FUN=scale)

dat %>%
    mutate(
        z_scored_residual = z_scored_achieved - z_scored_aim
    ) %>%
    group_by(
        group
    ) %>%
    summarise(
        z_scored_median = median(z_scored_residual)
        , .groups = 'drop'
    )
```

[image]

What do you think? Is the above a valid approach or are there better approaches? Maybe this is actually a great use case for the geometric mean? Thanks.

Comment: The right approach depends on what it means in your application to exceed the aim or fall short and on how you measure those gains and losses. In short, *you* need to provide a quantitative definition of "performance."  Because of this inherent dependence on your circumstances, there is no general statistical solution (and, IMHO, it would be wrong even to suggest one, since that would be tantamount to making these value judgments on your behalf).

Comment: @whuber very much appreciate your response. could you please provide an example as I am puzzled by what you mean. IMHO this is a maximisation problem. The larger the value is relative to the aim the better. The challenge is that one group has on average larger values than the other so I want to adjust for this comparing apples with apples.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you are maximizing.  Could you explain?

Comment: Let us say group a and b represent products and the person sells it for more than the aim?

Comment: Okay, but what is the reward and who gets it?  For instance, if this person needs to make a quota you might just count the cases where "achieved" exceeds "aim." If their quota is expressed as a proportion of their work, you might use the proportion of cases.  If you're doing this for the company, they might be interested only in the total difference between sales and targets.  If your purpose is to measure how well people perform relative to their targets, you might average the ratios of "achieved" to "aim."  These are just a few of the plausible loss functions one might use.

Comment: Yes the purpose is to measure how well people perform relative to the target. The issue is I want one performance measure despite having 2 groups. I contemplated  using multi objective rankkng

Answer (score -1):

Hi there I first wanted to add a comment before answering on this question, but it seems I have not enough reputation, to do this. Thus, I'll give my answer with a few assumptions and because of that, it will be longer as a comment. Maybe you will confound them instantly ;-)

When looking at the insights of your data, it seems that your two groups are already clustered, due to performance? Is it correct, that one group are the high performers and one group are the low performers? Or is this just coincidence? Or does this still has to be tested?

When looking at your data, it reminds me of a finished kmeans cluster analysis. When doing cluster analysis we scale the original data, before putting them into the analysis. YOu only have two dimensions and as you say more than two groups. So in general taking a mean of a scaled values seems not harmful.

Now to the question of the residuals
Looking at residuals/error of a model is usually a somehow a model agnostic(that means real knowdledge revealing) approach. In ML for instance we may use permutation importance to measure the importance of a variable/feature after permutating the feature(random shuffling its values) and looking if the error of the model is higher than before permutating, which indicates the feature had some meaning. The thing is that these approaches are independent of the indiviudal method chosen, e.g. coefficients of a linear regression or a logisitic regression (log odds) generate different importances and means.

Thus, I think that look at the residuals is somehow always better, as it shows, how close something was to what we expected, this is a better measure as how it performs, as the latter has no inherent benchmark. Thus the approach with the residuals may be ok imho, but only if you scaled your exogenous variables before attempting your model for your groups.

I hope you found my answer somewhat useful. If not, then we can maybe elaborate more together.

-----------UPDATE---------------

Is every row a point of time? Do you know the points of time? Is any individual in your dataset represented more than once, e.g. one time in `t0` and one time in `t1` or something like that? Because this reminds me of the fact that we arent allowed to do t-test or Anova on different groups if observations were gathered over time, and are ""not indepedent"" from each other: see also: [Using 2 sample T test in time series data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118425/using-2-sample-t-test-in-time-series-data)

If that is the case in your part please tell me, maybe we should  instead of scaling choose a useful rolling window size for both groups over time.
Then you would compare different means over time between both groups. That is allowed and useful. https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/difference-between-simple-exponential-moving-average/
You can compare simple rolling averages or rolling averages which focus more on actual data, thus on specific time points with weights.

So in case you really have not independent data and observations over time rolling comparions might do the trick, instead of scaling.

Comment: Thanks for that. The factor groups is indeed an ordinal variable. One expects larger values for group b in comparison to groups a. I guess my statistical confidence/knowledge is not strong enough to decide whether z scoring (or any other transformation?) is good enough to make this an apple to apples comparison and drop the factor group.

Comment: Atm im asking myself if you need scaling at all.. both variables seem to be at an equal scale already to compare them, what is the range of "achieved" and "aim" in absolute values. e.g. 0-130

Comment: Thanks but the median or any other average is just a reference point. the groups will have different variances/MDAs. so if someone is more part of one group (s)he may look worse/better depending on the priors?

Comment: I updated my post maybe we are now a step closer to your solution

Comment: thanks. anova is obviously related to regression. yes there are measurements over time of each individual not equally spaces. I really do not want to get out the armoury of hierarchical modeling, which  is most appropriated here ....

Comment: I believe it would be sufficient to look for appropriate windowsizes and build your rolling mean other both groups. That should be sufficient, perhaps you will end up with a few means to compare but at least that is more informative and more correct than just a simple mean in case of these various time points