# How to answer the question "Does promotion affect sales?" for this time-series dataset?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I'm doing a project on this time-series analysis that can be obtained from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/store-sales-time-series-forecasting/data?select=holidays_events.csv). The train.csv dataset has information about sales across different stores, products (or families) from 2013 to 2017. It also includes a feature called "onpromotion" which tells us how many items of a given product are on sale at a specific store, on a specific day. For example,

```
    Id   Date      Store   Family      ...  Sales   Onpromotion
     1   1-1-2013    1     Grocery I        50      0
     2   1-1-2013    1     Frozen Food      10      0
     3   1-1-2013    2     Grocery I        80      4
     4   1-1-2013    2     Snacks           200     50
    ...
```

I wanted to find out if there is a significant difference in sales of a specific product, at a specific store when it is on sale versus when it is not. I know that since it's a time-series data, we cannot use t-test for this. But I wonder if there is a way to work around it, or a different approach with a common time-series technique that I can use to answer this question?

Thanks

Comment: Start by understanding your dataset. Note that this is not a time-series dataset. It could be either a panel dataset or a pooled cross-section. If you have several characteristics on the exact same item over time - you have a panel dataset. But it is worth asking yourself if you can assume that Snacks in Store 2 in January 2013 is similar enough of a category to Snacks in Store n in Month YYYY. If you answer yes to that question and to similar questions pertaining to the other families of foods then you have a panel dataset.

Comment: @ColorStatistics I see. I think I'm going to narrow down to just one product at one store. In this way, the dataset will be a time-series one.

Comment: Because you care about both sales and promotion, 2 characteristics across time, even if you restrict to just one product at one store and only these 2 characteristics, you still have a panel dataset; or you can view these as 2 time series.

Comment: @ColorStatistics I see. Then what method can I use to determine if there's a relationship between promotion and sales? I found this answer at another post, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118425/using-2-sample-t-test-in-time-series-data, was wondering if the method of ARIMA+exogenous var is applicable to my data (how do I check this)? Thanks

Comment: If you are going to analyze time series you should start by plotting each series over time.